# ¿Cómo mostrar por consola iterando una lista de objetos en Java?

Tags: java, spring

instancio e inicializo varios objetos de tipos User

```
        User user3 = new User("user3", "correo@gmail.com", LocalDate.of(2004, 7, 24));
        User user4 = new User("user4", "correo@gmail.com", LocalDate.of(2004, 7, 24));
        User user5 = new User("user5", "correo@gmail.com", LocalDate.of(2004, 7, 24));
        User user6 = new User("user6", "correo@gmail.com", LocalDate.of(2004, 7, 24));
```

Después añado cada elemento a una lista

```
 List<User> list = Arrays.asList(camilo, matt, valeria, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6);
```

y quiero mostrar por consola cada elemento y lo estoy intentando con un for de la siguiente manera

```
  for (User user : list) {
            System.out.println("Se agrega el elemento " + user.getName());
            Logger.debug("Se agrega el elemento " + user.getName());
        }
```

Pero lo único que hace es que me muestra un valor null

```
Se agrega el elemento null
```

Y cuando llamo al objeto Log

```
2022-06-12 10:49:08.799 DEBUG 9540 --- [  restartedMain] c.f.s.f.FundamentosApplication           : Se agrega el elemento null
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser que `getName` está devolviendo `null`, porque si el usuario fuera `null` y la lista estuviera vacía, ni siquiera iterara y te lanzara un `NullPointerException`. ¿Puedes poner el código de tu clase `User`? Algo me dice que no estás inicializando el nombre correctamente o que tienes mal el getter.

Comment: puedes subir la clase User? sospecho que la constructora que tienes en esa clase, no hace nada si recibe el parámetro nombre, email y fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar tu clase User para ver como construyes tal objeto, de todas formas suponiendo que tienes 3 atributos como name, mail y dateOfBirth podrías hacer esto:

```
User user3 = new User("user3", "correo@gmail.com", LocalDate.of(2004, 7, 24));
//List.of() With Java 9 or +
List<User> userList = List.of(user3);
for (User user : userList) {
        System.out.println("Se agrega el elemento " + user.getName());
        Logger.debug("Se agrega el elemento " + user.getName());
    }
```

Tendrías un output como este:

```
Se agrega el elemento user3
```